# What is this strange usage of this idiom?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> Put your back in the task.

I found this but my dictionary says *"put ones back into ..."*

But here in the sentence "In" is used. Is it possible to change "into" into "in"?

Comment: Where did you find it? Who wrote it? Can you provide some context? ... I suspect this is a typo, or written by a non-native or non-standard speaker. Google does not give a single instance of "Put your back in the task". "Put your back in it", "put your back in the motion" are fairly widely used in hip-hop; but these are fairly literal descriptions of dance motions (probably with allusions to sex), not figurative descriptions of effort.

Comment: This is from Odyssey., I thrust us off and away, 
tossing my head for dear life, signaling crews 
to put their backs in the oars, escape grim death. 
They threw themselves in the labor, rowed on fast 
but once we’d plowed the breakers twice as far, 
again I began to taunt the Cyclops

Comment: When something is written in verse, it needs a certain number of syllables.  So changing "into" to "in" may make that happen.  Even if we would not make that change in normal speech.

Comment: Technically, it's not from the *Odyssey*, which is in very old Greek, but from a translation of the *Odyssey*. :) But it's quite a fine translation, and I'm grateful that you have called it to my attention.

Comment: Is Odyssey a difficult book? I have read Pope's version already.

Comment: i mean english wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the normal idiom in English is *put your back **into*** a task, a usually figurative use of what is in this case exactly the sort of literal meaning the idiom is drawn from—for a rower seated on a bench drives from his back and buttocks, not his legs.

But *put your back **in** it* is not entirely unknown—Google Books offers examples from every decade of the 20th century.

I think what drove the translator's choice here is, as GEdgar suggests, metrics:

> a kind of tug-of-war peculiar to translation: in this case, trying to capture the meaning of the Greek on the one hand, trying to find a cadence for one's English on the other, yet 
>   joining hands, if possible, to make a line of verse. I hope, at any rate, not only to give my own language a slight stretching now and then, but also to lend Homer the sort of range in rhythm, pace and tone that may make an Odyssey engaging to the reader.

Although he does not say so explicitly, it is obvious from even a brief glance at Fagles' translation that he is eager to preserve Homer's surging front-emphasized foot—that is, each foot reads *DA-da* or *DA-da-da* or (occasionally) *DA DA* rather than *da-DA* or *da-da-DA*, while allowing free variation between two- and three-syllable feet. (But in the final foot of a line Fagles accommodates himself to English by using mostly monosyllables, *DA*.) I have boldfaced the stresses in the lines you quote:

> ... I **thrust** us **off** and a**way**,
>   **toss**ing my **head** for **dear life**, **sig**naling **crews**
>   to **put** their **backs** in the **oars**, es**cape grim death**.

If he used *into* in that last line he would have three unstressed syllables between *backs* and *oars*, which he never permits himself. The line would have to be read

> to **put** their backs **in**to the **oars**

which would completely miss the natural rhythm of the idiom.

Comment: I also find..."We laid out with a will" in Samul Butler's version. Is this "lay out " what?

Comment: @user4550 It's a 19th century idiom (Butler was born in the 1830s, I think); I haven't ever heard it in speech. It means to "make an effort, to take trouble". I've usually encountered it as "he laid himself out **to** VERB*" = "he made a real effort to VERB" or "he laid himself out for PERSON" = "he went to a lot of trouble on PERSON's behalf". "With a will" means "with determination".

Comment: But I found lay also means to sail...so it means sail out?

Comment: @user4550 It doesn't mean *sail*. It is used in several nautical idioms with the ordinary meaning "place" or "set", as "lay a course", "lay by", "lay about", and so forth. The sense is transitive, with the object [the ship] implied.

Answer (score 0):

Some history:

'putting one's back into something' is a phrase that means putting extra effort into something. As for where it originated, my guess would be it had something to do with rowers on ships: they would move their back to get more motion out of the oar, hence putting their 'back' in (to) it.

The 'to' is optional. It is normally put in, but can be omitted when speaking informally.

Answer (score 0):

From my American perspective, I would say that the common usage here is:

> Put your back to the task.

I haven't heard the usage of "in the task" or "into the task". It sounds slightly odd to my ears.

Comment: I'm also US (albeit from a foreign country, Alabama!) and I've never heard *put your back **to***. What I *have* heard is *put your shoulder **to** the wheel*.

Comment: @StoneyB "foreign country, Alabama" :) Well I didn't think it was that foreign, but I do think it shows that what sounds right to one may sound a bit off to another. Good to hear both opinions, I think.